# How to find the number of positive integral solutions for the equations $\frac1x+\frac1y=\frac1{n!}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was trying to solve a question over hackerrank and the question link is [EQUATION](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equations)

How to approach for it?

Comment: Important omission in the question: according to the link the integer $n$ is **given**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :

$$ \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{n!} \Rightarrow x = \frac{n!y}{y-n!}$$

but $$  x \in \Bbb Z^+ \Rightarrow y-n! \mid n!y = n!y - n!^2 + n!^2 = n!(y-n!) + n!^2 \Rightarrow y - n! \mid n!^2$$

Comment: @Satish Patel sorry do you understand the answer ??

Comment: I think the given direction of the implications is the uninteresting one. With the opposite implications, the answer would be clearer.

Comment: @what'sup I am sorry, I'm trying to understand it by solving the predicate x being positive integer implies 
y-n!|n!y

Comment: if $ x = \frac{m}{n} $ and x is a positive integer so m must be divisible by n

Comment: @what'sup here on the stackoverflow the hint is given as by kiennt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650827/sample-testcase-for-interviewstreet-equations 
To express the N! in form of primes. See the link and answer comment by kiennt

Answer (score 0):

The general case $\frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{y} =\frac{1}{m}$ with x,y,m being positive integers can be written in the form:$m(x+y)=xy$ which implies that $(x+y)| xy$.

Let $gcd (x,y)=d$, with $x=dx_1 $ and $y=dy_1$ but $gcd(x_1 ,y_1)=1$. Because $(x+y)| xy$ we can see that $d(x_1+y_1)|d^2 x_1 y_1 $ and so we must have:$(x_1+y_1)|d $ because $x_1$ and $y_1$ are coprime.

So there exists a natural number $c$ with $x=c(x_1+y_1)x_1$ and $y=c(x_1+y_1)y_1$ and so, $m$ must be equal to $m=cx_1\cdot y_1$

This the general solution for every triplet (x,y,m).

In our case we must have $ m={n}!=cx_1\cdot y_1$
I hope this helps